# Shouldn't delphi generic functions be able to typecast?

Tags: function, delphi, generics, casting

I wrote what I hoped would be a useful function to avoid constantly accessing the database to look up a value based on a key: create a TDictionary in one big read and then use that.

But my nice code wouldn't compile:

```
function TBankImportCols.CreateDictionary<TKey, TValue>(const sql: string): TDictionary<TKey, TValue>;
var qry: TDataset;
begin
  result := TDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Create;
  qry := DM.CreateQry(sql);
  while not qry.Eof do begin
    result.Add(qry.Fields[0].Value, qry.Fields[1].Value);
    qry.Next;
  end;
  qry.Free;
end;
```

I got 2 errors:
[dcc32 Error] uBankData.pas(519): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TKey' and 'Variant'
[dcc32 Error] uBankData.pas(519): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TValue' and 'Variant'

This is using Berlin 10.1. It seems that the compiler should be able to sort that out. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

TIA
Mark

Comment: No, the compiler should not be able to sort that out. Certainly not at the time of compilation.The "type" of a Variant is set at runtime, i.e. unknown at compile time.

Comment: Why would generics help here? Just use concrete types.

Comment: Or just use a TDictionay<variant, variant>

Comment: @Dsm How do you hash a `Variant`? I could imagine that being rather challenging.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan; True.

Comment: Is the datatype of Fields[0] and Fields[1] known?

Comment: @RM: This is a pure guess, but ISTM that the datatype of the fields can vary between queries, and that OP **thinks** that the compiler can figure out which type to use (at runtime).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Data files in a column won't vary. More likely the asker just wants to have one function that can be reused with different queries, and therefore different columns and therefore different types.

Comment: @MarkPatterson What are the *actual* types of `TKey` and `TValue` when the errors occur? If they are built-in types, like `string`, `integer`, etc, then yes, one would expect the compiler to work out what code it needs to generate when *assigning* a `Variant` to them. Please [edit] your question to show an example of how `CreateDictionary()` is being used.

Comment: @David: yes, indeed, different queries, hence different data types. That is what I meant. For such code, one could use metadata and case statements and what-not, but this can **most definitely not be handled with generics**.

Comment: TValue, if you mean System.Rtti.TValue, is sort of a variant as well, and it even has a FromVariant method. But I don't  know how that would be better than a normal variant.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: There are no actual types. It doesn't compile. I had already done a <string, string> one and was going to do a <string, SomeRecord> one, so I wrote this intending to replace the existing one and make the next one easier.

Comment: Of course given s: string, i: integer and and v: variant, s := v and i := v will compile. But I guess a generic T is not precise enough for t1: T ... t1 := v to make sense to the compiler.